# Android virtual device failing to load at runtime

Tags: android

even if i'm trying just a simple android "hello world" program. On debugging following problem popping up..

`" the android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. the instance and2.2 (its the name of avd i hd created) is now stopped.
Reason:
The emulator process terminated unexpectedly: invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use'@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information"`

Answer (score 2):

it's probably because the path is in Program Files or something on Windows. Put the android sdk folder into a path without a space.

Comment: all i have checked it. but the problem still not resolving. I'm using eclipse so  how can change the path for android sdk as i had already specified?

Comment: go to Window->Preferences->Android and there should be a field for SDK location

Answer (score 1):

sdk path can't contain spaces.May be you changed your sdk path to somewhere like c:/program files/...Which contains spaces.Please place it in a directory which contains no spaces